# Regular Expression for text in between tags

Tags: qstring, qregexp

I have a QString that I need to parse. This QString is a QNetworkReply object obtained from an URL.

```
        <label id='Today_LastSale1'>$&nbsp;21.2401</label>
```

I need the value 21.2401 from the QString.

I am tried this.

```
       QRegExp rx("<label id='Today_LastSale1'>$&nbsp;(\\d)</label>");
```

But it returns -1. Need help with this.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just try to remove the non-numeric and "." characters from your string. Try regex replace with this expression: `"[^0-9\.]"`

## Code

```
QRegExp rx("[^0-9\\.]");
yourString.replace(rx, "");
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried  QRegExp rx("<label id='Today_LastSale1'>$&nbsp;[^0-9\.]</label>"); but it doesnt seem to work!

Comment: This code replaces every occurence of the pattern [^0-9\\.] with an empty string and returns reference to the string? Can you pls explain?

Comment: @user1065969, "^" negates the expression. So "[^0-9\\.]" will replace anyting except numbers [0-9] or "."